# Angular button needs two clicks the first time the page is loaded

Tags: angular, async-await, angular-promise

I want to create a validation function in Angular 6, where it checks if an object (a dish) already exists, based on the name.
First I want to perform my getDishes method, to be able to search for a match.

Everything works fine when my two methods are combined in one, but I wanted to clean up some code (also for learning purposes).

With the code of the two distinct methods below, I need two clicks before the console.log logs the name.

**UPDATE:**
I found the answer to the question myself after a lot of reading and trial and error, see my answer below. However, it seems so simple (too simple to be true?), can anybody tell me if this indeed a good solution?

**Initial question:**
So, can anybody tell my why:

1. I need two clicks, what happends exactly why the method is not performed in time? I guess it has something to do with async?
2. Is my workaround all right (using the code in OnInit)? In the end, the validation will always be necessary when adding a new dish.

   ```
   addDishWithDishExistValidation(): void {
   let dish = this.dishForm.value;

   for (let existingDish of this.getDishes()) {
     if (dish.name == existingDish.name) {
       console.log(existingDish.name);
     }
    }
   }

   getDishes(): Dish[] {
   this.dishService.getDishes()
     .subscribe(dishes => {
       this.dishes = dishes;
     });
   return this.dishes;
   }
   ```

However, When I put this part in OnInit, everything works fine:

```
    this.dishService.getDishes()
              .subscribe(dishes => {
                this.dishes = dishes;
              });
```

I did quite some research but could not find the answer for myself. Thanks in advance for the help!

**EDIT:**
After Antoniosss' comment I did some extra research and adapted my code. However, it still does not work, and the console.log(dishList) shows indeed that the array is still empty after the first click. How can I solve this?

```
async addDishWithDishExistValidation(): Promise<void> {
let dish = this.dishForm.value;

let dishList = await this.getDishes();
console.log(dishList);

for (let existingDish of dishList) {
  if (dish.name == existingDish.name) {
    console.log(existingDish.name);
  }
}
}

async getDishes(): Promise<Dish[]> {
await this.dishService.getDishes()
  .subscribe(dishes => {
    this.dishes = dishes;
  });
return this.dishes;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because on the first run:

1. You do your 'validation' agains EMPTY Dish array
2. You invoke async action to actually FETCH dishesh from service

On the second click action, async probably completes and then you validate agains some set of dishes.
As your validation is async, you should use async validators to do that.

This code is async!!

```
this.dishService.getDishes()
  .subscribe(dishes => {
    this.dishes = dishes;
  });
return this.dishes;
```

so on first run you only START `this.dishService.getDishes()` request, but you don't wait for it to complete, so you instantly returns `this.dishes` and that is empty.

After some time request completes (ajax remember?) and subscription is called - subscription is setting `this.dishes` array to whatever service had returned. That is why second run uses non-empty dish array. But it wont work anyway, as if you quickly add 2 times the same dish, validation will pass since it will use OLD dish array, and not the one that contains added dish.

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation! I edited some code and edited my question with this. Can you maybe explain what I am doing (still) wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So.. after a lot of trial and error, and reading and trying a whole lot of methods using async and await I finally found the solution.

I just needed to add toPromise() after the service. For some reason it seems to simple, is this truly a good solution?

```
  getExistingDishes() {
    let existingDishes = this.dishService.getDishes().toPromise();
    return existingDishes;
  }
```

And the method in which it is used:

```
 async addTest() {
    let existingDishes = await this.getExistingDishes();
    ...
 }
```